# This query still returns empty title field?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

this query works perfectly apart from it still returns blank title fields:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT( TRIM( LEFT(title, 
    IF( LOCATE('10 Pack', title), LOCATE('10 Pack', title) - 1, 
    IF( LOCATE('100 Classic', title), LOCATE('100 Classic', title) - 1, 
    IF( LOCATE('100 Favourite', title), LOCATE('100 Favourite', title) - 1, 
    IF( LOCATE('DVD', title), LOCATE('DVD', title) - 1,
    IF( LOCATE('Bluray', title), LOCATE('Bluray', title) - 1,
    IF( LOCATE('Series', title), LOCATE('Series', title) - 1,
    IF( LOCATE('20 ', title), LOCATE('20 ', title) - 1,
999 )))))))))), 
    main_category, 
    genre, 
    actors
FROM 
    PRprodINFO 
WHERE
    ((main_category = 'Films') 
    AND (length(title) > 2)) 
GROUP BY title
```

also tried:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT( TRIM( LEFT(title, 
    IF( LOCATE('10 Pack', title), LOCATE('10 Pack', title) - 1, 
    IF( LOCATE('100 Classic', title), LOCATE('100 Classic', title) - 1, 
    IF( LOCATE('100 Favourite', title), LOCATE('100 Favourite', title) - 1, 
    IF( LOCATE('DVD', title), LOCATE('DVD', title) - 1,
    IF( LOCATE('Bluray', title), LOCATE('Bluray', title) - 1,
    IF( LOCATE('Series', title), LOCATE('Series', title) - 1,
    IF( LOCATE('20 ', title), LOCATE('20 ', title) - 1,
999 )))))))))),
    main_category, 
    genre, 
    actors
FROM
    PRprodINFO
where 
    ((main_category = 'Films')
    AND (title <> ''))
GROUP BY title
```

but still blank title field rows are returned...any ideas why?

Thanks

Darren

Comment: Can you give some examples of typical rows in the `PRprodINFO` table? Particularly the `title` column. Also, what is the goal of your query?

Answer (score 0):

If a field is `null` then `LOCATE(astr, field)` will return null.
You need to make sure `title` is not null.
Either replace `title` with `COALESCE(title)` everywhere or do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT( TRIM( LEFT(i.title, 
  IF( LOCATE('10 Pack', i.title), LOCATE('10 Pack', i.title) - 1, 
  IF( LOCATE('100 Classic', i.title), LOCATE('100 Classic', i.title) - 1, 
  IF( LOCATE('100 Favourite', i.title), LOCATE('100 Favourite', i.title) - 1, 
  IF( LOCATE('DVD', i.title), LOCATE('DVD', i.title) - 1,
  IF( LOCATE('Bluray', i.title), LOCATE('Bluray', i.title) - 1,
  IF( LOCATE('Series', i.title), LOCATE('Series', i.title) - 1,
  IF( LOCATE('20 ', i.title), LOCATE('20 ', i.title) - 1,999 ))))))))))
  , i.main_category, i.genre, i.actors 
FROM (SELECT main_category, genre, actors, COALESCE(title,'') as title 
      FROM PRprodINFO) i 
WHERE ((i.main_category = 'Films') AND (length(i.title) > 2)) 
GROUP BY i.title
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add the following to your WHERE clause...

```
AND Length( TRIM( NVL(title, '' ))) > 2
```

instead of your

```
AND (title <> '' )
```

If you have any NULL values, those will throw it off, Additionally, if a title has a value of "     ", that too could give false positive.  So, by doing an NVL() (if null value, use the ''), then trimming that, then checking the length... you should get all qualified for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your massive `IF` block so that it returns `title` when none of the conditions are met. What are the results?

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT( TRIM( LEFT(title, 
    IF( LOCATE('10 Pack', title), LOCATE('10 Pack', title) - 1, 
    IF( LOCATE('100 Classic', title), LOCATE('100 Classic', title) - 1, 
    IF( LOCATE('100 Favourite', title), LOCATE('100 Favourite', title) - 1, 
    IF( LOCATE('DVD', title), LOCATE('DVD', title) - 1,
    IF( LOCATE('Bluray', title), LOCATE('Bluray', title) - 1,
    IF( LOCATE('Series', title), LOCATE('Series', title) - 1,
    IF( LOCATE('20 ', title), LOCATE('20 ', title) - 1,
999 )))))), title )))),
    main_category, 
    genre, 
    actors
FROM
    PRprodINFO
where 
    ((main_category = 'Films')
    AND (title <> ''))
GROUP BY title
```